# Error "An array may not have elements of this type"

Tags: c++, arrays

I`ve problem compiling my program because of this strange compile error...here is the concrete part of code:

```
 // the error occures at "char _adr[][]" in the constructor parameters

Addresses(string _ime, string _egn, char *_adres, char _adr[][], int adrLen):Person(_ime, _egn, _adres){
    addressLength = 0;
    for(; addressLength < adrLen; addressLength++) {
        if(addressLength >= 5){
            break;
        }
        adr[addressLength] = _adr[addressLength];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `adr` defined at?

Comment: You should specify last column size in definition:
`char _adr[][256]`

Comment: multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C/C++ you cannot define a bi-dimensional array with two unknown size as in `char _adr[][]`. Arrays declarations must have all, but the first, sizes defined. Try defining at least one size (example: `char _adr[][10]`) or, since you are using C++, use an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Just to make you notice it: you are also using the `adr` without declaring it in the scope of the function.