# Constructo containing a 2D array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, constructor

I am trying to make a second constructor that contains a 2D array, but I can't seem to get it to work. If you need any more information just ask, I'll do my best to supply and answer.

**Node.h**

```
struct data
{
   string record;
   string ID;
   string name;
   string email;
   string units;
   string major;
   string grade;
   int absent;
   char missed[32][32];
};

class List;


class ListNode
{
   friend class List;
   friend struct data;
   public:
   ListNode();
   //ListNode(data newData);
   ListNode(string newrecord,
            string newID,
            string newname,
            string newemail,
            string newunits,
            string newmajor,
            string newgrade);
   ListNode(string newRecord,
            string newId,
            string newName,
            string newEmail,
            string newUnits,
            string newMajor,
            string newGrade,
            int newAbsent,
            char dates[][32]); // this constructor
   ListNode(ListNode &copyObject);
   ~ListNode();

   data getData() const;
   ListNode *getNextPtr() const;

   ListNode & operator = (ListNode &rhs);

   private:
   data mData;
   ListNode *mpNext;
};
```

**In Node.cpp**:

```
 ListNode::ListNode(string newRecord,
                   string newId,
                   string newName,
                   string newEmail,
                   string newUnits,
                   string newMajor,
                   string newGrade,
                   int newAbsent,
                   char date[32][32] )
{
   mData.record = newRecord;
   mData.ID = newId;
   mData.name=newName;
   mData.email=newEmail;
   mData.units=newUnits;
   mData.major=newMajor;
   mData.grade=newGrade;
   mData.absent=newAbsent;
   memcpy(mData.missed, date, sizeof(date)); //attempt at copying
   //mData.missed = date;


   this->mpNext = NULL;
}
```

**In Linkedlist.cpp** This is where the error starts:

```
ListNode *List::makeNodeM (string newRecord,
                           string newId,
                           string newName,
                           string newEmail,
                           string newUnits,
                           string newMajor,
                           string newGrade,
                           string newAbsent,
                           char dates[32][32])//here and
{
   ListNode *pMem = NULL;
   pMem = new ListNode(newRecord,
                       newId,
                       newName,
                       newEmail,
                       newUnits,
                       newMajor,
                       newGrade,
                       newAbsent,
                       dates); //here    
   return pMem;
}
```

Comment: 2d array of what? 2d array of strings?

Comment: @Abhi It is a 2d array of chars. It is [32][32]

Comment: Is it giving any error?

Comment: @YasirMajeed yeah I put comments in the code where the errors are occuring.

IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "ListNode::ListNode" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, char (*)[32]

Comment: just replace  char dates[32][32] with char dates[][].

Comment: @YasirMajeed it says that "arrays  may not have elements of this type"

Answer (score 0):

When you use an argument such as

```
char date[32][32] )
```

the compiler ignores the size of the first dimension. It is as if you had used

```
char date[][32] )
```

Given that, `sizeof(date)` is the same as `sizeof(void*)`.

Which means, the line

```
memcpy(mData.missed, date, sizeof(date)); //attempt at copying
```

doesn't copy what you are hoping it will. Replace that line with a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i )
{
    memcpy(mData.missed[i], date[i], sizeof(data[i]));
}
```

Comment: Besides this do you know why it is giving me the syntax errors in my Linkedlist.cpp

Comment: @Montop20, I can't answer that since you didn't post the definition of the class `List`. You posted just the implementation of `List::makeNodeM`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution applicable to your problem is [Error "An array may not have elements of this type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079041/error-an-array-may-not-have-elements-of-this-type)

Just replace the code in Node.cpp with the following

```
          ListNode::ListNode(string newRecord,
               string newId,
               string newName,
               string newEmail,
               string newUnits,
               string newMajor,
               string newGrade,
               int newAbsent,
               char date[][32] )
             {
            mData.record = newRecord;
            mData.ID = newId;
            mData.name=newName;
            mData.email=newEmail;
            mData.units=newUnits;
            mData.major=newMajor;
              mData.grade=newGrade;
             mData.absent=newAbsent;
             memcpy(mData.missed, date, sizeof(date)); //attempt at copying
           //mData.missed = date;


           this->mpNext = NULL;
     }
```